# Java : How to use scanner.hasNextLine without Ctrl+Z in a console program

Tags: java, console-application, java.util.scanner

Say I have the below code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     line = scanner.nextLine();
     //do something
    }
```

And my input in the console is goes like this.

```
Wayne Rooney
Luis Nani
Shinji Kagawa
```

I want to read this line by line.

But the problem is the method hasNextLine blocks waiting for the input after the third line as the input from the keyboard (System.in) never reaches EOF.

Now, how do I reach EOF just by pressing enter key? because I don't want to tell the user to press the Ctrl+z to run my program.

How is it generally done? Any thoughts?

I am looking for a solution from the Java side and not any commands on the console.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a special key word (e.g. quit).

Comment: Thanks. But again, I don't want the user to be doing anything other than just giving the input and pressing enter.

Comment: The problem is that the program does not know whether you are finished or you want to add another name after you've pressed enter.

Comment: You have exactly two choices: 1) make the user do something special to indicate EOF, like a _real_ EOF (Ctrl+Z), an empty line, or entering a special string like "QUIT"; or 2) quit yourself after processing 3 lines, which means your program will always expect exactly 3 lines of input.  There is no way to magically read the user's mind to determine when they're finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How is it generally done?*: It is usually done by showing a message to the user and requesting some *special word* to finish the input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;

    System.out.println("Enter names (\"QUIT\" to finish)");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("QUIT")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

In the example above the *special word* used is `"QUIT"`, of course you will change this to a more appropriated one.

Answer (score 2):

When you press enter twice, you end up reading an empty line. You can test for this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.equals(""))
        break; // this will exit the loop
    //do something
}
```

Now, the loop will end if you press enter twice without typing anything between.

Comment: Thanks, but as I had mentioned earlier, I want a less intrusive solution. I don't want the user to be doing anything other than giving the input and pressing enter

Comment: @shazinltc: There is no other way then. You need to somehow differentiate between user input and signal to end.

Comment: You can decide to only process up to 3 names, there's a different way to do that...