# PushbackInputStream read() not returning -1

Tags: java, io

In Java API for the read() method, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html

The read() method returns the next byte of data from the input stream.

And then there's this useful feature:

```
 Returns:
      the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.
```

I discovered that manually inputting an arbitrary input into the console does not return -1 when the input stream reaches the end of said input. For example, I could enter (+ 1 2). The code would read the input, put elements into tokens and parse it just fine.

However when it reaches the end of the input after line feed (ASCII decimal code: 10). The read() does not return -1. I need the -1 in order to stop the parser from executing more. Instead of returning -1, it just prompts the user for a new input in the console.

After some thought, I think it will only return -1 when EOF is detected, which can be only done with a input file, not manually inputting in the console. Does this sound right? Is there any tricks such as inserting EOF into the console input, so that the inputstream read() would actually return -1?

Or should I just start using input files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enter [Ctrl+Z: *"It is also used to signal an end-of-file on some operating systems."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z)?

And no, just start using input files doesn't sound right. An input stream can be obtained from various devices such as network interface, USB port, keyboard, mouse, HDD (file), A/D converter card and the like.

Comment: That was a promising venture. I entered (+ 1 2) then Ctrl + Z into the input, but it still prompts the user after line feed. Didn't work, but thanks for the try! I'm on Windows 7 by the way.

Comment: A quick [DDuckinG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+console+enter+eof) brought as 3rd result [Java : How to use scanner.hasNextLine without Ctrl+Z in a console program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246472/java-how-to-use-scanner-hasnextline-without-ctrlz-in-a-console-program). Maybe this helps further.